# Why does it only print 4 values from a 2d list?

Tags: python

I am making a contacts Terminal app as a mini project and I cant figure out how to show all contacts.
I thought of having a for loop for it based on its length, like this:

```
 for i in range(len(contactBook)):
     print(contactBook[0][indexToPrint], contactBook[1][indexToPrint])
     indexToPrint += 1
```

Its a part of a funtion:

```
    indexToPrint = 0
    if not contactBook:
        print('Your contacts are empty')
    else:
         for i in range(len(contactBook)):
            print(contactBook[0][indexToPrint], contactBook[1][indexToPrint])
            indexToPrint += 1
```

I can input an infinite amount of contacts but it only prints 4 values(2names & 2 numbers)
This is the whole code, how can I get it to print more, or all contacts?

```
contactsBookNames = []
contactsBookNumbers = []
contactBook = [contactsBookNames, contactsBookNumbers]
def seeYourContactList():
    indexToPrint = 0
    if not contactBook:
        print('Your contacts are empty')
    else:
         for i in range(len(contactBook)):
            print(contactBook[0][indexToPrint], contactBook[1][indexToPrint])
            indexToPrint += 1

def toAddContact():
    while True:
        toAdd = input("Would you like to add a contact? ")
        if toAdd == "Yes":
            addingContact()
            break
        else:
            seeYourContactList()
            break
def addingContact():
    contactsBookNames.append(input("What name do you want for this contact? "))
    contactsBookNumbers.append(input("And now for the number... "))
    addingMore()
def addingMore():
    while True:
        toAddpt2 = input("Would you like to add another contact? ")
        if toAddpt2 == "Yes":
            addingContact()
            break
        else:
            seeYourContactList()
            break
toAddContact()
```

Comment: Probably because `contactBook` is an Nx2 list-of-lists, instead of an 2xN as your code assumes. Show us the output of `print(contactBook[0])`,`print(contactBook[1])` to check that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `contactBook` is an Nx2 list-of-lists, instead of an 2xN as your code assumes. You need to `print(contactBook[0])`,`print(contactBook[1])` to check that, and please edit the output of that into the question.

As to your loop:

- you want to run loop-variable `i` over `len(contactBook[0])`, not `len(contactBook)`
- it doesn't need separate variable `indexToPrint` duplicating what `i` is already doing

So change your existing code:
indexToPrint = 0
for i in range(len(contactBook)):
print(contactBook[0][indexToPrint], contactBook[1][indexToPrint])
indexToPrint += 1

That's just a very a convoluted way of saying:

```
for i in range(len(contactBook[0])):
    print(contactBook[0][i], contactBook[1][i])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of this line:

```
len(contactBook)
```

No matter how long your list is, `len(contactBook)` will always print `2` because your list is 2D. So, that is why you are only getting 2 lists (4 as total) as output. So, in order to tackle with the problem, you have to iterate inside one of its list using `len(contactBook[1])` or `len(contactBook[0])`

So use this code:

```
contactsBookNames = []
contactsBookNumbers = []
contactBook = [contactsBookNames, contactsBookNumbers]
def seeYourContactList():
    indexToPrint = 0
    if not contactBook:
        print('Your contacts are empty')
    else:
         for i in range(len(contactBook[1])):
            print(contactBook[0][i], contactBook[1][i])

def toAddContact():
    while True:
        toAdd = input("Would you like to add a contact? ")
        if toAdd == "Yes":
            addingContact()
            break
        else:
            seeYourContactList()
            break
def addingContact():
    contactsBookNames.append(input("What name do you want for this contact? "))
    contactsBookNumbers.append(input("And now for the number... "))
    addingMore()
def addingMore():
    while True:
        toAddpt2 = input("Would you like to add another contact? ")
        if toAddpt2 == "Yes":
            addingContact()
            break
        else:
            seeYourContactList()
            break
toAddContact()
```